# verey Slow when use IN in table mysql 46.4878 sec

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

Very very slow in the query when using IN

this query

```
SELECT *
FROM engine4_comment
WHERE sid IN (10,12,548,2110,5241,1255)
```

and this create table

```
CREATE TABLE `engine4_comment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted_reason` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `send_email` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `dep_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `dat_idx` (`date`),
  KEY `rid_idx` (`rid`),
  KEY `rsid_idx` (`rid`,`sid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=719329 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

and when use explaine `explain SELECT * FROM`engine4_comment`WHERE sid IN (10,12,548,2110,5241,1255)`

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  engine4_comment     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    875583  Using where
```

Comment: Removed sql-server tag because query is clearly MySQL syntax.

Comment: what about Drop this rsid_idx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM engine4_comment
WHERE sid IN (10,12,548,2110,5241,1255)
```

For performance, you want an index on `sid`.  Either include a `KEY` statement in the `create table`.  Or, explicitly create an index:

```
create index idx_engine4_comment_sid on engine4_comment(sid);
```

Note that the index `rsid_idx` doesn't help for this query, because `sid` is the second column.  An index on `(sid, rid)` would benefit this query.